# Right Name in Horizontal Axis

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

Goal:
I would like to have month name "January" and "February" in horizontal axis for the boxplot.

Problem:
I tried to do it but I failed. Having "Month" and "Names" as text in horizontal axis is not right.

```
mydata

#       Month Count
# 1   January    10
# 2   January    11
# 3   January    22
# 4   January    55
# 5   January     4
# 6   January    88
# 7  February    44
# 8  February    40
# 9  February    30
# 10 February    28
```

Here is the `dput` of `mydata` :

```
mydata<-structure(list(Month = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("February", "January"), class = "factor"), 
    Count = c(10, 11, 22, 55, 4, 88, 44, 40, 30, 28)), .Names = c("Month", 
"Count"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the result of `boxplot(mydata)` :

[image]

Comment: Your boxplot is correct, in the sense it is showing the distribution of `Month` and `Count`. It is totally wrong, as your goal is to show `January` and `February`. It is not a problem of tick name.

Comment: That is true and thatis why I need some support please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do :

```
boxplot(df$Count~df$Month)
```

it will return :

[image]

If you want to display January then February, do :

```
df[,1]<-factor(df[,1],levels=c('January','February'))
boxplot(df$Count~df$Month)
```

or just :

```
boxplot(df$Count~df$Month,names=c('January','February'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is it possible to start with January and then February in  horizontal axis?